# EKS cannot debug node once marked as NotReady

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

This question maybe related to [EKS node moves to NodeNotReady state when running a batch jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67914767/eks-node-moves-to-nodenotready-state-when-running-a-batch-jobs?noredirect=1#comment120044370_67914767). I am wondering how can I stop from my node from getting deleted once it is marked as NotReady.

I am seeing that as soon as the Node is marked as NotReady, it gets removed and there is no way to debug it and log into the node and go through the logs.

I am not sure what can be done to stop the Node from getting deleted